# Addition of a positive number and a negative number

Tags: javascript, addition

I made a function to move an element base on there left CSS value. My function work in one direction but I realize a strange problem in the other direction.

First I extract the left value of a element :

```
$left_position = element.css('left').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, ''); // left_position = -400
```

now when I add a positive value to that, for the new position :

```
$new_left_position = $left_position + 400;
```

The result I was expected was 0 but instead the result is : **-400400**

If I replace the "+" sign by a "-" sign it work the result is -800

Any idea why?
Thanks

Comment: Cast the element to Integer before doing operations =)

Comment: ... using `parseInt()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse it to integer, you are concatinating it because one element ($left_position) is a string.

```
$new_left_position = parseInt($left_position) + 400;
```

function ".replace()" will ofcourse always return a string so your variable is a string aswell.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript the `+` sign is for string concatantion on strings.

```
var string = "400";
console.log(string + 400); //400400
console.log(parseInt(string) + 400); //800
```

Comment: + is not only for concatinating, its a mix and JavaScript interpreter decides wether to concatinate or do math operations depending on data-types. However if only one of the both variables is a string a math operation is impossible and it will use concat

Comment: This is why i wrote: `on strings`.

Comment: Yea I just placed it because it looks somewhat incomplete, I dont said its wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `ParseInt('$variableName')` you can achieve your desired result.

I hope following will also helpful in your work. Using simple jQuery code you can move things easily as follows:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="To Left" onclick="moveStuff('-=100px')" />
<input type="button" value="To Right" onclick="moveStuff('+=100px')" />
<div id="stuff" style="padding:10px;background-color:#ff00f0;width:120px">I AM MOVING</div>
```

jQuery Function:

```
function moveStuff(px) {
$('#stuff').animate({
    'marginLeft' : px
 },1000);
}
```

WORKING SOLUTION on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/xewawu/1/edit)